# splitting parameters rather than declaration

Tags: clang-format

I'm trying to get `clang-format` to do my bidding, and stumbling on one point.  I want my C function declaration to be formatted as:

```
sensor_t *sensor_enable_alarm(sensor_t *sensor, 
                              float lo_thresh, 
                              float hi_thresh);
```

but with my current settings, clang-format wants to format it as:

```
sensor_t *
sensor_enable_alarm(sensor_t *sensor, float lo_thresh, float hi_thresh);
```

I've initialized my .clang-format from llvm via:

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

and modified just the `BinPackParameters` to be false:

```
BinPackParameters: false
```

What additional tweaks to .clang-format do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine` to a larger value. The default value for LLVM style is `60`. Try `200`, which is the default for `Google`, `Mozilla`, and `Chromium` styles.

For example, `clang-format -style='{BasedOnStyle: LLVM, BinPackParameters: false, PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 200}' yourfile.cpp` gives this output:

```
sensor_t *sensor_enable_alarm(sensor_t *sensor,
                              float lo_thresh,
                              float hi_thresh);
```

As always, see the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) for more information. However, unfortunately, there really isn't much there to explain the "Penalty" values.